# Task switching in Ubuntu is painfully slow

Tags: ubuntu

Whenever I switch tasks in Ubuntu (ALT+TAB), the switch takes place instantaneously but I have to wait a second before I can use the new screen because the task preview window comes up **after the switch**, stays on the screen for a moment and then disappears before I can use the new screen. Anyone know how to fix this?

("task preview window" = the window that displays miniature views of each of your open tasks)

Comment: I'm assuming you are using Compiz? Are all the other effects running well?

Comment: I can't find any indication that compiz is installed (but I'm not sure how to check definitively). I understand it's more resource-heavy. Is that why you asked? Yes, no other display problems.

Comment: You can check if compiz is installed using `dpkg`. `dpkg -l | grep compiz`

Comment: John T: Thanks for the command. Yes, it is installed. I don't see an entry for it under System -> Preferences or any of the menu items underneath the Appliations menu on the taskbar.

Comment: I wonder if disabling compiz would be enough to speed things up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try disabling compiz from 'System->Preferences->Appearance' then go to the 'Visual Effects' tab and check 'none'. Then try switching windows and compare the results.

I find the compiz task-switcher completely unusable and unfortunately there is no way to disable only the compiz task-switcher, you have to disable all effects. So, it's your choice, usability or fanciness!

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with alt+tab and compiz in Ubuntu 9.04. But after upgrading to Karmic everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. The following solves the slow task switching problem for me in Ubuntu 16.04.  It massively speeds up the following (from ~1 second = painfully slow, to near instantaneous):

   - speed of switching windows via click
   - speed of switching windows via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
   - speed of menus opening via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+[menu shortcut key] (Without this, using a text editor, I can click <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for the File menu, then <kbd>C</kbd> for Close, and it will write the letter “C” into the text file before the file menu even appears.)

**ccsm -> Desktop -> Viewport Switcher = OFF**

2. Further, you can turn off the window preview entirely like so, which also speeds things up, and prevents the annoying flicker for when the preview disappears then the real window appears (when it could/should be seamless always, yet is not):

**ccsm -> Window Management -> Application Switcher -> General -> Focus on Switch = OFF**