# GUI slow when switching programs or opening application list

Tags: ubuntu, performance, ubuntu-16.04, gui, user-interface

I think I'm having issues with some cache or something similar.

This results in the following issue: When I try to switch the open program using `[Alt] + [Tab]`, the preview of programs takes a while to show up, and it takes another while until the new program is opened.
If I click on the top left "Search your computer" icon, even the mouse starts lagging and I can watch the list of programs slowing fade in.

I've found this question: [Task switching in Ubuntu is painfully slow](https://superuser.com/questions/66909/task-switching-in-ubuntu-is-painfully-slow), but the accepted answer doesn't seem to apply to Ubuntu 16 (I cannot find this 'Visual Effects' tab).
However, the [second answer](https://superuser.com/a/1327360/439432) did completely fix my issue - unfortunately, only for a day.

After disabling the "Viewport Switcher", everything became as fast as I would expect it to be. And after a day, it was just as slow as it used to be. So now I switched the "Viewport Switcher" back on - and for now, it's fast again.

Obviously, the "Viewport Switcher" doesn't cause my issues, but toggling this setting appears to reset something else, maybe restart some service or delete some caches? How can I permanently fix this problem?

Comment: Have you considered updating to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, which might resolve the issue? You can test from a live USB without having to install it. Bonus: 18.04 should be maintained for another 8 years.

Comment: That's indeed something I'm planning to do - in 3 months, after I've completed an important task. Right now, I cannot risk breaking anything of my setup because I don't have the time to fix it.
So if no one knows how to properly fix this bug, I'll just keep toggling that setting on and off for the next 3 months, but obviously I'd like to have a permanent solution. But thank you very much, nevertheless, @DrMoishePippik!